# How to test whether fields are only allow numeric values (by selenium IDE)

Tags: selenium, validation

I have a form and it has some specific fields those only allow numeric values.

My question is i want to test this that those fields only allow numeric values using selenium IDE

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your application under test behaves, but for the case that your mentioned inputfields don't accept typed in values, the following code could do what you would like to do. The following code is written in Java and uses the Selenium 1 API and JUnit.

```
type("inputfieldlocator", "hello");
String fieldVal = getValue("inputfieldlocator");
assertEquals("", fieldVal);
```

As per request as follows the code as selenium IDE html.

```
<tr>
  <td>assertNotValue</td>
  <td>inputfieldlocator</td>
  <td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>inputfieldlocator</td>
  <td>hello</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please provide this in Selenium IDE script (in html). Cheers